# Is degreed the same as graduated?

Tags: meaning

I'm translating a sentence

> the standards are approved by the customer or degreed
>   metallurgist/equivalent as applicable

but I'm not quite sure about 'degreed'. Is it the same as graduated or qualified? I couldn't even find it in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *degreed metallurgist* is the same as *someone holding a degree in metallurgy*.

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/degreed) lists the word as meaning:

> **degreed** (*adj.*) [education] having an academic degree

[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/degreed) lists it as well.

Essentially, it's about the same as *graduated*, in that you are awarded a degree when you graduate from an academic program.